# Scrollbar for every view (View class)?

Tags: android, view, scroll, scrollbar, scrollview

I was just reading few stackoverflow threads about scrolling views larger than parents. Everywhere is used ScrollView or HorizontalScrollView for this, but what is puzzling me is why does every single view have methods and xml attributes for setting scrolling? For example, Im currently overriding method `onScrollChanged()` of View class. I mean can every view have a scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

Because View is a class/Object.

To give you a more to the point example here you go:

public class Test extends View {
}

Therefor, it's pretty much obvious for View to have methods for each instance of the object.Right?

Comment: That's not what im asking

Comment: Sorry, I was sleepy and might have understood the whole thing wrong.